# Magento 2: How to generate category url with underscore?

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite, url-key

I am importing categories from external script. All working fine with import.
But with URL KEY Magento is changing value automatically.   And I want the url same as I am passing from script.

```
1) Man_Jeans-1-1  //I am passing from script
2) man-jeans-1-1  //Magento saving like this
```

1st one is the value that is passed from script like,

```
$cleanurl = "Man_Jeans-1-1";
$category->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
```

But value is automatically changed like 2nd one.   Is there anyway I can fix this issue?
 I don't want Magento to change the url key.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Urls with `Underscores(_)` cannot be considered as a valid url because `Underscores(_)` are not allowed in a host name & other thing is also there that search engines like google are not recognizing those url which contains `Underscores(_)` with them. For better understanding do refer [this](https://www.woorank.com/en/blog/underscores-in-urls-why-are-they-not-recommended)

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for the ans. But we need this anyhow. There is no issue with SEO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the cleanest way to do it as it modifies a core file, but if you edit the following file:

> vendor/magento/framework/Filter/TranslitUrl.php

Change line 23 from:

`$string = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', parent::filter($string));`

to:

`$string = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z_]+#i', '-', parent::filter($string));`

Then edit and save the category page via the back-end that seems to work.

Comment: It is indeed not a good approach. But you can implement these changes with a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this trying to do the same thing of allowing underscores in the category url. Thought I would share my approach to allow the underscores.

**Strategy 1: TranslitUrl After Plugin**

[image: TranslitUrl class method]

Even with an after plugin defined on the `TranslitUrl` class, the plugin didn't seem to fire.

As it turns out, the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::formatUrlKey()` method does not call `TranslitUrl` directly. It makes a magic method call that `\Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager` handles to indirectly instantiate and use the `TranslitUrl::filter()` method.

**Strategy 2: Preference on TranslitUrl class**

Started down the path of creating a preference to completely replace how `TranslitUrl` filters/formats url keys.

After thinking through it, altering `TranslitUrl` might not make sense as it's a low level utility class. Having a plugin or preference here would alter all usages of this class, possibly having unintended side effects elsewhere.

**Strategy 3: Plugin on Category class**

The `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::formatUrlKey()` method might be a better place for a customization. From what I can tell, the `formatUrlKey` method is the only place in the Catalog module responsible for handling formatting of url keys.

[image: Catalog Category - Format Url Key Method]

In `app/code/[Vendor]/[CustomModule]/etc/di.xml`:

```xml
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category">
    <plugin name="vendor_custommodule_allow_underscore_urls"
            type="Vendor\CustomModule\Plugin\AllowUnderscoreUrls"
            sortOrder="0"/>
</type>
```

In `app/code/[Vendor]/[CustomModule]/Plugin/AllowUnderscoreUrls.php`:

The ultimate change still being to alter the regex to prevent `_` (underscore) from getting replaced with a dash

`preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z_]+#i', '-', $this->translit->filter($str));`

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomModule\Plugin;

class AllowUnderscoreUrls
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly \Magento\Framework\Filter\Translit $translit
    ) {
    }

    public function afterFormatUrlKey(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $subject,
        string $result,
        $str
    ): string {
        if (!str_contains($str, '_')) {
            return $result;
        }

        $string = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z_]+#i', '-', $this->translit->filter($str));
        $string = strtolower($string);
        $string = trim($string, '-');

        return $string;
    }
}
```